# Is tor really fully decentralized?

Tags: tor

I think, somewhere an initial list of the connectable peers had to download. Manipulating this list, or the server providing this list, weren't a serious security compromise of the whole network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to start from somewhere to ask about where nodes are, but that doesn't mean you have to use one of the ones that are in the provided list.  You can use whatever node you trust.

Every distributed system requires asking for other systems that are part of the network, otherwise you would just have to try IPs at random until you found someone providing the service you are looking for.

It is decentralized because peers will tell each other where to find more peers.